# Is there a way to show ListView.builder inside CupertinoAlertDialog in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, dialog, size, overflow

I am trying to use ListView.builder inside CupertinoAlertDialog as the content using Flutter. I do **NOT** want to force its height to a predefined value. Instead, I want it to take the minimum space (dynamically depending on the item count) it requires from the available area.

The example corresponding **code section**:

```
await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                title: const Text('LKJASDasd'),
                content: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) =>
                        Text(i.toString())),
                actions: const <Widget>[],
              ));
```

The solutions I tried gives the following **error**:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.

If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, you should be able to achieve that effect by just giving the viewport loose constraints, without needing to measure its intrinsic dimensions.

The relevant error-causing widget was
CupertinoAlertDialog
```

I tried to use Column with MainAxisSize.min or SingleChildScrollView, however they did not work. Since I do not want to force its height, SizedBox, ConstrainedBox, or other widgets do not work for me.